# Mercurial: copying ONE file and its history to another repository

Tags: mercurial

I'm wondering if I can copy one file and its history from one repository to another, without having to import the *whole* other repository.

Comment: As an alternative, you could commit a copy of the file, with a pointer to the repository and the revision id.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the [ConvertExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) to export just that one file from the first repository into a new temporary repository, then use `hg pull -f` to import the new repository into the target repository.

Create a filemap for the ConvertExtension with the single line:

```
include path/to/file
```

Then use:

```
hg convert path/to/original path/to/temporary --filemap filemap
```

to create the temporary repository.  Next, in the target repository, do:

```
hg pull -f path/to/temporary
```

to pull in that file with its history.  This will create a new head, so use `hg merge` to merge it with the head in your target repository.

Comment: I don't get it: I've made a lot of tries, and almost every time Iget a repository with just two commits (but with the correct files). It worked just ONCE and I don't have the slightest idea on what I did different :|

Comment: ffs I got it: it doesn't handle file renames! You have to explicitly "include" all the previous names of the files too (and I don't know if he will remember they were renames instead of new files)

Comment: Hi! I follow this method but I can't push the result, it says " push create new remote head on branch [an old branch that is closed]" What can I do?

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to Niall C.'s answer, you can rename the files you are importing to place them at the correct place too.

You must first rename the file, then include it. Your filemap would look like that:

```
rename "original/path" "wished/path"
include "original/path"
```