# Converting Mercurial folder to a Git repository

Tags: git, mercurial

I don't have a huge experience with Mercurial, I'm mostly a Git guy.

I would love to mirror a specific Mercurial folder/file in a git Repository. What I'm actually trying to do is to export the history of a file from a Mercurial repository to Git and being able to keep this in sync with future commits.

Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed? I believe that the way to go should be to get the history of the Mercurial patch, periodically export every single commit as a patch and apply the Mercurial patches to the Git repository.

Comment: Nowadays, GitHub.com will [import it *for you*.](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer)

Comment: Related: a good walk-through on git-scm.com: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git#_mercurial

Answer (score 128):

On **Linux** or anything with `bash/sh` or similar, or `python`, try with [fast export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export):

```
cd
git clone git://repo.or.cz/fast-export.git
git init git_repo
cd git_repo
~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo
git checkout HEAD
```

Comment: I know about fast-export, but it doesn't solve my issue because it exports the entire repo and the original repo is more than 1.5GB.

Comment: Ok, you want to keep git synchronize with mercurial ? Like [this](http://syntensity.blogspot.fr/2011/02/synchronizing-git-mirror-with-hg-git.html) ?

Comment: Or you can use Mercurial [outgoing hook](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) to push to git ?

Comment: I have no control over the original HG repository, I need each new commit to be submitted also in the GIT repo by pulling the original HG repo.

Comment: Note that '/path/to/old/mercurial_repo' must be a path on the file system (not a URL), so you have to clone the original repository before.

Comment: In my case had to use `PYTHON=python2 ~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo`. Apart from that, it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for concise answer!
I had to `sudo easy_install mercurial` first. Would be nice to have in the instructions

Comment: If you are on Windows machine **use the Git bash** and run _hg-fast-export.sh_

Comment: I had to run `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH` because hg-fast-export depends on Mercurial as a library.

Comment: If you are getting the error `ImportError: cannot import name revsymbol` the simplest solution is downgrading fast-export to v180317, that is `cd ~/fast-export; git checkout v180317`. More details [here](https://github.com/frej/fast-export/issues/132).

Comment: I wrote a quick post on my blog with some more details to [convert a Mercurial repository to Git](https://www.guguweb.com/snippet/convert-a-mercurial-repository-to-git/). There are also some tips if you are using Bitbucket.

Comment: @MarcusWestin is there a way to do this without that command? I don't have sudo permissions on my machine so I can't execute that to install the module "mercurial"

Comment: The repo.or.cz site might be slow to respond. It also lives on https://github.com/frej/fast-export

Answer (score 67):

### Windows: TortoiseHG Hg-Git extension

[Hg-Git](https://hg-git.github.io/) can be used to convert a Mercurial repository to Git. You can use a local repository or a remote repository accessed via SSH, HTTP or HTTPS.

#### Example of local repositories conversion.

1. Install Hg-Git.

   - On Windows, [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) comes with Hg-Git, though you need to [enable it](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nonhg.html#hg-git-git) via the setting tool (in extensions section)

     [image: TortoiseHg Settings]

     or manually in `~/mercurial.ini`

     ```
     [extensions]
     hggit =
     ```
2. Use the following commands to convert the repository:

   ```
   $ mkdir git-repo; cd git-repo; git init; cd ..
   $ cd hg-repo
   $ hg bookmarks hg
   $ hg push ../git-repo
   ```

The `hg` bookmark is necessary to prevent problems as otherwise hg-git pushes to the currently checked out branch confusing Git. This will create a branch named `hg` in the Git repository. To get the changes in master use the following commands (only necessary in the first run, later just use `git merge` or `rebase`):

```
$ cd git-repo
$ git checkout -b master hg
```

Comment: I've found git-hg to be quite buggy, but this worked like a charm, and didn't require any additional downloads which is nice.

Comment: I wanted a folder, not the entire repo.

Comment: github now has a tool that supports this directly from github, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037787/convert-mercurial-project-to-git

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3643313/1429387). It should help you to export a file/folder and its history in a temporary repository. Then you can use any of the provided solutions to convert the temporary Mercurial repository to Git.

Answer (score 13):

You can (from Mercurial side):

- using [Convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) with `--filemap` option convert part of original repo into smaller with only needed files|directories
- with hg-git extension push stripped repo to Git

or (instead of hg-git), using [Mercurial bridge in Git](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/), clone|pull repository from Git

Answer (score 11):

## Gitify

Seems as a more modern and easy to use alternative to perform the conversion
https://github.com/buchuki/gitifyhg

```
pip install gitifyhg
git clone gitifyhg::<hgrepoaddress>
# done, you have a git repo with the entire history of the hg one
```

Comment: I didn't want to convert an entire repo, just a folder.

Comment: Awesome! Beware of unicode error though https://github.com/buchuki/gitifyhg/pull/98

Comment: Note - gitifyhg is currently badly out of date with the latest Mercurial versions.

Answer (score 8):

## Convert a Mercurial repository to Git on Windows 10

### If no problem with encoding - use TortoiseHG Hg-Git extension

```
md new-repo && cd new-repo
git init --bare .git
cd ..\old-mercurial-repo
hg bookmark -r default master
hg push ..\new-repo
cd ..\new-repo
git config --bool core.bare false
```

### If something wrong with encoding - use fast-export

#### Install Bash

Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1604-lts/9pjn388hp8c9?rtc=1&source=lp&activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

#### Open Bash and run

install mercurial

```
sudo -s
apt-get update
apt install mercurial
```

get fast-export v180317 (at the moment versions after 180317 does not work correctly)

```
cd /mnt/c/path_to_work_folder
git clone https://github.com/frej/fast-export.git
cd fast-export
git checkout tags/v180317
cd ..
```

convert repository

```
git init new-repo && cd new-repo
git config core.ignoreCase false && git config core.quotepath off
../fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r ../path_to_mercurial_repo/ --fe cp1251
git checkout master
```

encoding options:

- `-f` encoding, like `-f cp1251`
- `--fe` file name encoding like `--fe cp1251`

Answer (score 3):

## hg-git-fast-import

https://github.com/kilork/hg-git-fast-import

Another utility with the following features:

1. Import of single and multiple Mercurial repositories to Git repository.
2. Import of new revisions from previously imported Mercurial repositories to Git repository.
3. Tags.
4. Closed branches.
5. Verification of the end result with diff.

You may download binary for you [platform](https://github.com/kilork/hg-git-fast-import/releases) and put somewhere in path or install with `cargo` (require `rust` to be [installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started)):

```
cargo install hg-git-fast-import
```

Then usage is like this:

```
hg-git-fast-import single /path/to/source_hg /path/to/target_git
```

It does not need `Python` and `Mercurial` to be installed. Advanced configuration allows to replace authors or branches, make branches prefixed and more.

Comment: a good tool, but it seems to be neglected these days and does not handle much of what you might find in the .hg/requires file in recent mercurial versions

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **github.com**, they appear to have **an import feature** that lets you simply type in the URL of your hg project.

First **create a new repository** and then on the new repository's landing page scroll to the bottom and click the **"Import code" button**.

[image: context for the import code button]

Then type the **URL of your previous repository** and hit "Begin import".

[image: context for "Begin import" button]

Then GitHub takes care of the rest!

[image: Github taking care of business for you]

Note that GitHub will ask you for your credentials for the old repository if it needs them.

Ooh! I found the [official guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer)

Answer (score -1):

On Windows can be a bit tricky. After enabling the right plugins in mercurial( `hggit`), the TortoiseHG can also be used.

1. Clone mercurial repo
2. Clone git repo
3. Enable console :
   [Enabling console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN8mg.png)
4. Using the console :

   `% hg bookmarks hg`

   `% hg push <relative path to>/<git-repo>`