# How to use Hg-to-Git tool - fast-export?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I have tried the instructions from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037787/convert-mercurial-project-to-git):

```
cd ~
git clone git://repo.or.cz/fast-export.git
git init git_repo
cd git_repo
~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo
git checkout HEAD
```

However when doing `git checkout HEAD` it throws:

```
error: pathspec 'HEAD' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

What is the work-around for this?

**Update:**

I managed to install mercurial-python howen when I try to import still it would not work, the error is:

```
Error: No --marks option given
```

When doing:

```
C:\fast-export\hg-fast-export.py -r C:\path\to\repo
```

Comment: Did the `~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo` command generate any errors? It sounds like you don't have any commits in your Git repository.

Comment: @Chris My Hg repository have lots of commits which I need to export to Git.

Comment: @Chris, oh I see one error when I try to run hg-fast-export.py instead: No module named mercurial

Comment: Does regular Mercurial work from the command line? Try `hg --version`.

Comment: @Chris I manage to fix the Hg issue, I have updated my post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running `hg-fast-export.sh` instead of `hg-fast-export.py`. It looks like the shell wrapper includes an option for `--marks` for you.

Comment: In Windows it throws './hg-fast-export.py' No such file of directory

Comment: `hg-fast-export` doesn't appear to be designed for (or tested on) Windows, as it lacks a `.bat` wrapper. If you want to try it anyway, try this: ``hg-fast-export.py -r path\to\hg\repo --marks .git\hg2git-marks --mapping .git\hg2git-mapping --heads .git\hg2git-heads --status .git\hg2git-state``. This is roughly taken from the shell wrapper. There is some caching and stuff that we're not doing here, but it shouldn't break. You may have to create an empty `.git\hg2git-marks` file first.

Comment: I know this is 3 years later, but it took me a day and half trying to work all this out. Adding the `--marks ...` stuff above to the Python call doesn't work, but if you're doing this in Windows, **use the Git bash**. In there, you can use the shell script and it works just fine.

Comment: it still does not work on windows for me even from under Git bash.