# Is it possible to merge and link two unlinked repos on Github?

Tags: git, github, merge, repository

I have a repo on Github that was imported from Google Code (actually, someone else imported it and I forked it). The original project has been dormant on Google Code since 2011. The code is mostly in a single file in the root directory. My fork has the Google Code history. We've made additions to the code.

A third person has also imported the original source to Github, and made changes. Someone forked that and added some more.

(There are other similar Google Code->Github clones, so it might be useful to do something similar with some of those too.)

I would like to somehow unify these, I'd like:

- to merge the other repo's changes into mine, and
- to keep the history of their commits.

Ideally, I'd also like:

- somehow link each repo, perhaps so their network graph's are linked (on Github), and
- allow future PRs to be made easily between forks.

So:

1. What's the best way to do this?
2. Is the second part even possible?
3. If not, what's the best way around it?

Comment: was the Google Code repo already in Git? or were these repos converted from some other VCS?

Comment: The Google Code repo's Mercurial.

Comment: could you link to the repo(s) in question?

Comment: @NevikRehnel: Yes, [mine](https://github.com/hugovk/pylast) and [one of the others](https://github.com/mattjeffery/pylast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the mercurial repo, you can start by [converting it to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037861/6309) (`fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh`).

And regarding the possibility to link two different histories (for two branches of unrelated repo), you can use git grafts (graft point) to make a common history.

See for instance "[How to rebase one Git repository onto another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428339/6309)" (`.git/info/grafts` + [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)).

Comment: The Mercurial Google Code repo has already been converted and imported to Git by someone else. That's the basis of my fork. // Thanks, I'll have a go with graft, it sounds like it can do (1). // Any idea of (2) and (3)?