# Move code from Mercurial to Bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

Currently, I have Mercurial as my version control in Kiln server. I want to migrate my code to Bitbucket server with Git. I have tried the [import](https://bitbucket.org/repo/import) option available in Bitbucket but I can only import as a Mercurial repository.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do the `Mercurial -> Git` conversion on your own machine with a tool like [`fast-export`](https://github.com/frej/fast-export).

You then create a new repo on Bitbucket and follow the instructions to push your project to it. You shouldn't hit any major roadblocks.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037861/129782) will give you further information on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Except the fast-export tool, there is an easy way to migrate Hg to git:

#### Initial a local git repo

```
mkdir git
cd git
git init
```

#### Clone hg repo

```
cd ..
hg clone <URL for hg_repo>
cd <hg_repo>
hg bookmarks hg
hg push ../git
```

#### Get changes from hg repo in local git repo

```
cd ../git
git checkout hg
```

#### Create an empty git repo on bitbucket, and push local git repo to it

```
git remote add origin <URL for bitbucket repo>
git push -u origin hg
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `abort: repository ../git does not exist!` while executing the following command `hg push ../git`

Answer (score 1):

I have a very positive experience with [git-remote-hg](https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg).