# Converting Mercurial to Git using TortoiseHG. No files are created

Tags: git, mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to convert a Mercurial project to a Git project. I am following the directions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34853438/984003 using TortoiseHG.

1. Enable hggit
2. Open a command line, enter an empty directory.
3. git init --bare .git
4. cd to your Mercurial repository.
5. hg bookmarks hg
6. hg push c:/path/to/your/git/repo
7. In the Git directory: git config --bool core.bare false

After the push command, it said

added 5815 commits with 24723 trees and 24178 blobs

So something happened. But, when I go to repo directory (the path that I pushed to), it's empty except for .git

Comment: Have you tried to checkout to some changeset?

Comment: I'm completely new to Git, hence the conversion from Mercurial :)  Checkout from where?

Comment: @user984003 it's the same as in mercurial - you need to `git checkout` to a particular revision, check it with `git log`

Comment: @torek hasn't they "unbare" it on the step 7?

Comment: @zerkms There's no history, no version, no branches, nothing.

Comment: @torek I just tried and it works to me :shrug:

Comment: @zerkms: oh, I see what's going on here: the idea is to write the Git repository to `.git`, so that instead of `X.git`—which you'd then clone to `X` to create `X/.git`—you have something that, when you remove the bare-ness, is supposed to make its *parent* directory become the work-tree. That could actually work, if everything lines up just right. (I don't have TortoiseHG so I can't test these exact steps as shown.)

Comment: @torek yep, there is a chance that's what OP might have been missing PS: I did not do all those steps, I made it up and I DID specify that `.git` manually (given I know it) :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zerkmas was right in the comments.

From c:/path/to/your/git/repo, do:

```
git checkout hg
```

And then all the files appeared.

EDIT: In the end, this didn't work out for me either. It loses the branches.

I ended up using GitHub's importer:

[Convert Bitbucket Mercurial repository to Git. Maintain branches and history. Online solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716968/convert-bitbucket-mercurial-repository-to-git-maintain-branches-and-history-on/57716969#57716969)

Comment: The only problem for a company that produces closed source is that you can't use services like GitHub.