# cannot push my mercurial repository to git from tortoisehg

Tags: git, mercurial, tortoisehg

After getting my repository by tortoisehg
and activating the hggit by tools, i'm trying to push my mercurial project on a gitlab repository.
it ask me to enter my credentials and check multiple times, and i'm 100% sure i don't make any mistake.

i can enter on the tortoisehg my git commands and do the following commands

```
git add -p
git commit -p
```

but when i'm trying to push on my gitlab i get the following error:

> HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal:
>
> Authentication failed for 'my repo url.git'

Comment: Related, not sure if this is a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68055482/3195477

Answer (score 0):

I know only one recent version of THG, which can work with bundled hg-git (namely TortoiseHg version 6.0+9-77d0054d9222)

Even this THG works **only** with ssh-repos, i.e. have smth. like

```
[paths]
default = git+ssh://***.git
```

in repo's hgrc and you **must have** usable ssh-key authentication for repository

Comment: Finally, it's impossible to sync the HG repo and the GIT repo due to some restriction on each side...

Comment: @VincentBUQUOY-BLANC - with THG 6.2.* I had to move to `git+https://` remotes and **can use pull+push** with bundled hggit