# Migrating from Mercurial to Git

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, version-control-migration

I know this question asked before several times and marked "possible duplicate", but none of them seems working correct. I tried fast-export and it gives error. Could anyone help How to migrate from Mercurial to Git? I need the history. It would be appreciated if it is listed step by step.

**UPDATE:**

I tried fast export:

```
cd ~
git clone git://repo.or.cz/fast-export.git
git init git_repo
cd git_repo
~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo **[I get error in this line]**
git checkout HEAD
```

this gives error:

..... hg-fast-export.sh: line 79: python: command not found

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This S.O. question contains a lot of options and links to documentation (not only the fast-export option): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710250/converting-mercurial-folder-to-a-git-repository

Comment: If you expect us to help you, ***please add more details to your question***. What commands are you using to do the migration? Are there any error messages? What have you already tried that isn't working? The more info you give, the more we can help you!

Comment: @MF82 I exactly followed that link. See my update

Comment: how is your python installed?

Comment: @mnagel I installed the python-2.6.6.msi.

Comment: So, what's happening on line 79 of that script? And does the answer of Lazy Badger solve that?

Comment: @MF82 I don't know what is happening on line 79. I am not very familiar with python. I was going to try Lazy Badger's suggestion, but was very confusing (i think that is lack of my English).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add hg-git to Mercurial
2. Push hg-repo to git-target

## Step-by-step Guide

A Clone [Hg-Git Extension](http://hg-git.github.io/) from [it's repository](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/) into some local PATH\TO\HG-GIT

B Enable extension in (global mercurial.ini or repository's-specific .hgrc)

```
[extensions]
bookmarks = 
...
hggit = PATH\TO\HG-GIT
```

bookmark was added long time ago, when this extension wasn't part of TortoiseHG|Mercurial, not sure about today's configuration

C Create new Git-repository with read|write access to it (or remeber existing?!)

D Add Git-repo from p. C into `[paths]` section of .hgrc for Mercurial repository, which you want to export in Git under any name. Sample for my local Mercurial repository, which have Git-mirror on Github

```
[paths]
default = git+ssh://git@github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git
```

E After it you can use Git-repository as usual remote repository in Mercurial and, as fist operation (for created empty Git-repository) you have to push to your new remote

F Check existence of Git-repository with full history from Mercurial mirrored into it after push

G Use Git-repository by usual way

### Sources, used in this guide

- Local Mercurial repository of WP-theme with very easy linear history

[image: Local repo in Workbench]

- [Git-mirror](https://github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n) of this repo on Github

[image: Mirror]

Comment: Could you please provide more steps?

Comment: @Dilshod - yes, answer expanded (will be) now

Comment: Thanks for posting everything. I am trying to add extension to my HG, but it is not showing up on the list of extensions. This is how I tried. hgext.bookmarks =
hggit = C:/hg_builds/hg-git. and I tried the path with back slashes "\" and with quotes. Not sure whats wrong.

Comment: @Dilshod - I never used pure Mercurial (only THG), thus - can't say anything in this area

Comment: stuck on the the point (D), how do you build the "git+ssh://git@github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git" string?