# migrate Hg to Git via "fast-export" in Windows

Tags: git, mercurial, azure-devops, git-for-windows, fastexport

I have a project having mercurial HG code source management,and try to migrate it on a VSTS/Git platform.

I read that there is a tool for doing that, "[fast-export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export)"... So I tried but not did't achieve to do it working in Windows...

Say I have `D:\MyProject` containing the `.hg` directory and the project code files, I

- downloaded the `fast-export` files in the "D:\fast-export-master" folder,
- created a new directory `D:\MyProject-git`
- launched in that `D:\MyProject-git` the `git init` command (a new `.git` directory appeared then);
- now from the same `D:\MyProject-git` i did
  `..\fast-export-master\hg-fast-export.sh -r "D:\MyProject"`

now strange things starts happening, a command line window appeared and disappeared so quickly I didn't understood what happened, so I relaunched the previous command in a hope to see the message... I should  try tens of times until able to capture in the printscreen the command-line message, that says strange things:

> which: no D:\fast-export-master\hg-fast-export.sh in (/c/Users/xxx/bin:mingw64/bin:/user/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/xxx/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32 *[...etc...etc...]*)

I wonder what is the problem and how to solve it...

**EDIT:**

Following the @max630 suggestion bellow, I reinstalled Python and update the PATH, so it's recognized in the command

```
> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

opened the "GIT Bash" from the start menu then

```
cd "/D/MyProject-git"
../fast-export-master/hg-fast-export.sh -r "D:\MyProject" --force
```

that gave:

```
../fast-export-master/hg-fast-export.sh: line 175: python: command not found
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-fast-import.exe statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Objects allocated:       5000
...
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want to add tag "git-for-windows" because this is what you most probably are using. Since there is limitation of at most 5 tags you'd have to remove some.

Comment: I installed git for windows, but I don't really use it, I use Visual Studio Team Services GUI, that uses git in background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concern is that you imported the "hg-fast-export" into a directory that was not added to your environment variables, according to the error message "D:\fast-export-master\hg-fast-export.sh" was not found in the list of your environment variables, so try to add th following "D:\fast-export-master\"in your environment variables and then try again.

If it does not work out yet, look at this article and follow step by step what was said:

https://www.appveyor.com/blog/2014/02/23/converting-mercurial-repository-to-git-on-windows/

The author has copied the directory "hg-fast-export" into the new directory git (without the .git of "hg-fast-export") and has also added hg, git and python to his environment variables.

good luck

Comment: I followed the article steps, but at the moment `hg-fast-export.sh -r c:\projects\demoapp -A authors.txt` it didn't find hg-fast-export, probably because of what your are saying I have no Path EnvironmentVar, so I open the Git Bash in the demoapp_git folder and then did `$ /c/projects/demoapp_git/hg-fast-export.sh -r "C:\projects\demoapp" --force` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

> Following the @max630 suggestion bellow, I reinstalled Python and update the PATH

Starting with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), you will have to install Python 3, since the `hg-to-git` script (in `contrib/`) has been updated to work with Python 3.

See [commit d17ae00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d17ae00c97d3edbe548a0aaa64ac37bfc9440809) (18 Sep 2019) by [Hervé Beraud (`4383`)](https://github.com/4383).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8f53fe1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f53fe1733bbfbebc5e8dce087b8229165d1c4bf), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `hg-to-git:` make it compatible with both python3 and python2
>
> **Python 2 is EOL at the end of 2019**, many distros and systems now come with python 3 as their default version.
>
> Rewrite features used in `hg-to-git` that are no longer supported in Python 3, in such a way that an updated code can still be usable with Python 2:
>
> - `print` is not a statement; use `print()` function instead.
> - `dict.has_key(key)` is no more; use "`key in dict`" instead.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, it took me a while to get hg-fast-export to work, but I eventually got there.  Here are some issues I ran into:

- I needed to install Python and also had to add the Python binary directory to the system PATH.
- The instructions say to run hg-fast-export from a git bash window.  On my first attempt I could not even cd to the correct directory, because my bash shell had me "jailed" to my home directory hierarchy.  I changed the git bash shortcut to Run as Administrator, removed the --cd-to-home argument, and set it start in C:.  Note that once you start the shell, paths will start with /c/.
- After issuing command **git init** to create an empty repo, I also had to issue **git config core.ignoreCase false** before the export would go further.

  - Next I got the error "ImportError: No module named mercurial".  I had done a binary install of TortoiseHg but it needed sources.  I downloaded Mercurial sources and added the root source directory to the system environment variable PYTHONPATH.  Then I re-launched git bash.
  - Now the git-fast-export worked!
  - As documented, **git status** will show all files as "deleted".  Issue the command **git checkout HEAD**, repeat **git status**, and it should show "nothing to commit, working tree clean".

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours and hours trying many of the above solutions, and nothing worked well for me. I tried the fast-export and the hggit in tortoisehg in numerous variations.

In the end I used the [GitHub Importer](https://github.com/new/import) to import all of my mercurial repository into GitHub.

I just needed to provide the URL of the repository (mine was in BitBucket), and it was a very smooth and easy process. Much smoother than trying to get python working in git bash, path variables, etc!

I also had some significant local changes that I could not push to bitbucket because they're not allowing pushes. So I had to copy those files manually into the git repository.

I also could not get teamcity to detect the changes when switching from VCS roots from bitbucket to github. So I created a new project in team city.

I hope this helps anybody who is facing these challenges.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the bash bundled with git. It does not initialize "$@" properly if started from directly running .sh file from cmd.

Open "GIT Bash" from start menu, then issue commands:

```
cd "/D/MyProject-git"
```

to navigate to `D:\MyProject-git`, and

```
../fast-export-master/hg-fast-export.sh -r "D:\MyProject"
```

to run your script

Comment: *"Error: The option core.ignoreCase is set to true in the git
repository. This will produce empty changesets for renames that just
change the case of the file name"* so I used `--force` to skip this check, but then *"../fast-export-master/hg-fast-export.sh: line 175: python: command not found"*

Comment: i reinstalled Python, restarted the PC, retried: but anyway `../fast-export-master/hg-fast-export.sh: line 175: python: command not found`... checked the hg-fast-export.sh on the line 175, there is a comment there, any "python" command...

Comment: it should be in you PATH. Also I don't know if python for windows would work in msys environment

Comment: I added in the Path, now it recognizes "python" in the command line, however the error message in git batch is the same... I found similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970341/migrating-from-mercurial-to-git but is crazy i should also clone the Hg-Git  extension...

Comment: You could try to install [g4w sdk](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/tag/git-sdk-1.0.6), where you could install python built for msys2, not the windows one. But it might be that the script you picked is not that ready for use. I cannot say in general how to convert repositories, I have done it only once, with some hg extension, and the repository was small so that it did not require involving with fast anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already installed TortoiseHg, there has an easier way to migrate hg to git.

First, enable hggit in TortoiseHg:

TortoiseHg -> global setting -> Extensions Tab -> select hggit -> OK.

[image]

Then use below commands to migarte and push to VSTS git repo:

```
# In an empty folder
mkdir git
cd git
git init
cd ..
hg clone <URL for Hg repo>
cd hgrepo
hg bookmarks ../git
cd ..
cd git
git checkout hg
git remote add origin <VSTS git repo URL>
git push origin --all
```

Comment: Thanks. After `hg clone` there should'n be `cd <repo name>`?

Comment: `C:\mygit\git>git checkout hg
error: pathspec 'hg' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Oh, yeah, it should use `cd <hg repo name>` after `hg clone`. I updated it in my answer, please try again.