# Move a Mercurial repo into a sub-directory of an existing git repo

Tags: git, mercurial

How can I move a Mercurial repo into a sub-directory of an existing git repo?

fast-export and other approaches use an empty repo

Comment: Do you want to convert the HG repo to Git? Or do you mean you want to leave it as an HG repo but place it within a git repo's directories?

Comment: I want to be completely git and one repo, so I want to import the HG repo contents into a folder within the GIT repo. I don't want to use HG after this is done

Comment: This is one approach which should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223912/3195477

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Nohow

### Longer answer

Because:

1. Git from a box can't work with Mercurial repos directly
2. Repo in folder of a repo is Git's [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [subtrees](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_subtree_merge) (subtree is better - less headache - way)

you have:

1. Convert Mercurial repo to Git
2. Use this Git-repo in parent in preferred by you way

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little on my comment:

1. Use the [`hg convert`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) feature with the `--filemap` option to modify the existing HG repo so that the folder structure looks like what you want. For instance, move everything into a subfolder called `/from_hg`.
2. Use one of the available tools like hg-git to convert the modified hg repo to a git repo
3. Merge from the converted git repo into your main git repo. Now you will have subfolder `/from_hg` in your git repo. Your git repo has two unrelated start points. This is quite similar to Linus Torvald's "[coolest merge ever](https://gist.github.com/trOmy/8a98b3876fc775c7b027)" I think.

This procedure is somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223912/3195477.