# Fast export fails with "The system cannot execute the specified program" migrating hg to git

Tags: git, migration, mercurial

I'm trying to convert mercurial repository into git using `hg-fast-export` but getting following error when I'm trying to run

```
path/to/hg-fast-export.sh -r path/to/mercurial-repository
```

error:

> The system cannot execute the specified program.

[image: and here is another error]

I have already added path for `git`, `mercurial`, `hg` in environment variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Mercurial folder to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710250/converting-mercurial-folder-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon, I already referred that but no one mention an error there similar to above error