# Visualhg wont install for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visualhg

The install won't complete, I get this message:
[Download Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M90Gr.png)

And this is the Install Log:

```
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - -------------------------------------------
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - 17.1.1035-preview2
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - -------------------------------------------
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - Command line parameters:
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\rebek\Downloads\VisualHG.vsix
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - -------------------------------------------
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
4/7/2022 8:37:31 AM - -------------------------------------------
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Initializing Install...
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Extension Details...
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Identifier         : DADADA00-dfd3-4e42-a61c-499121e136f3
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Name               : VisualHG
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Author             : Bernd Schrader
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Version            : 1.1.7
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Description        : Mercurial source control integration
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Locale             : en-US
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   MoreInfoURL        : http://visualhg.codeplex.com/
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   InstalledByMSI     : False
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0]
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Supported Products : 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           Version : [10.0,11.0)
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           ProductArchitecture : x86
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           Version : [11.0,12.0)
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           ProductArchitecture : x86
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           ProductArchitecture : x86
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           Version : [14.0,15.0)
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -           ProductArchitecture : x86
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   References         : 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       -------------------------------------------------------
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Version      : [10.0,)
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       MoreInfoURL  : 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -       Nested       : No
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Signature Details...
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM -   Extension is not signed.
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - 
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Searching for applicable products...
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Found installed product - AtmelStudio
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2019
4/7/2022 8:37:34 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you see _"This extension is not installable on any currently installed products."_ in the error. From the [VisaulHG page on VS MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualHG.VisualHG) _"Version 1.1.7 is compatible with MSVS 2010 - MSVS 2015"_ on

Answer (score 1):

Even if VisualHG isn't maintained, you can use Mercurial natively from VS2019 with [VSHG](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=d-popov.vshg)

> a fork of VisualHG, which **works with Visual Studio 2019** and Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score -2):

You should move to Git or use Hg from the command line

**Hg extensions are no longer maintained**

The error says :

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

The [VisualHG installer in VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualHG.VisualHG) was last updated in 2015 and only targets up to VS 2015. It can't support VS 2019 and is now abandoned. Some people have cloned the code from Codeplex to [a Github repo](https://github.com/BerndSchrader/VisualHG) but there's no activity there either.

You can use a different extension, eg [HgSccPackage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zz-sergant.HgSccPackage) although even that project [is now archived](https://github.com/zzsergant/HgSccPackage).

You should seriously consider migrating to Git. Mercurial simply isn't that popular any more, and hasn't been for more than 5 years. In the distributed version control space Git is the undisputed king.

**Migrating to Git**

The question [Git interoperability with a Mercurial Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository) has several answers that show how Git can be used with a remote Hg repository.

The answers to [Converting Mercurial folder to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710250/converting-mercurial-folder-to-a-git-repository) show how you can clone an Hg repo to Git. On Windows 10 you can use WSL to use any Linux tools or scripts needed to convert the repository

The Git Manual's [Migrating to Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) has a section on Mercurial that explains what tools are needed and what they do.